# rails select the bigger count/longest data from array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, select, hash

i have a array of hashes like this

```
data = [{code: 'a', expire1: '10', stock1; '10', expire2: '11', stock2; '15'}, {code: 'b', expire1: '10', stock1; '10', expire2: '11', stock2; '15', expire3: '12', stock3; '25'}, {code: 'c', expire1: '10', stock1; '10'}]
```

i want to select the data with the longest/biggest count of every hash inside, so the output is must like this

```
{code: 'b', expire1: '10', stock1; '10', expire2: '11', stock2; '15', expire3: '12', stock3; '25'}
```

how can i do that ??

Comment: get the hashes with each {} , flatten and compare the length, inject may be a choice since you could pass the result of the previous comparison

Comment: any example of that ? i've no idea how to use inject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`Enumerable#max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by)

```
>> data.max_by(&:length)
=> {:code=>"b", :expire1=>"10", :stock1=>"10", :expire2=>"11", :stock2=>"15", :expire3=>"12", :stock3=>"25"}
```